# UITableView Thinks it is Taller than it is when use as inputView

Tags: ios, uitableview

For a custom widget, I want to display a list of items in the modal slide-up way that you get from setting a view as the `inputView` on a widget (that is, it replaces the keyboard for that widget).

I can do this with no issue, but when I set a UITableView as the `inputView`, it seems to think it is taller than it is.  I can scroll all the way past the bottom so that the last item is not even displayed.  When there are fewer items than fill the area it adds blank rows way past the bottom of the visible area as well.

Is there something about the `inputView` area that causes stuff to not know how tall its container is?  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of using a `UITableViewController`, we wrapped it (in the storyboard) in a normal `UIViewController` with a table view in it, and that seems to be working fine.